# .NET 2013 RDLC Reports, Date Formatting

Tags: visual-studio-2013, rdlc, date-formatting

I have created a report in RDLC (using Visual Studio 2013). in which I have a date field. I wanted to display the date field as 01-Jan-2015. Hence I have formatted the date field using `Format(Fields!LICDate.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")`.

However, I get a varied output in the date field. For some date the date is formatted correctly, for example the records having the date as 28th November 2015 are displayed as **28-Nov-2015**, but some records this displays weird characters. Like, if the date is 1st October 2018, it shows ***01-OcA-2018***, for 1st March 2016, it shows ***01-3ar-2016***

I have browsed through web and got various links that show examples of date formatting in RDLC and almost all the links suggest using of `Format` and some links have suggested using `.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")`. I tried both the suggestions but the result is the same.

Am at loss on what has actually happened. The data in the database records is correct and whn I display int he DataGridView it shows correctly. This problem occurs in RDLC reports only that too for a few records only.

Any suggestions or links to solutions for similar problems are welcome.

Comment: What do you get from executing `System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");`? I mean if run the code in a console application?

Comment: In Code, everything is OK. This is the problem in the RDLC reports only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Format, try to right click on that text box and go to Properties/Number, then select Custom from Category and in Custom Format enter dd-MMM-yyyy.
This should fix your problem.

Here is link that can help you: [VS report designer 2005-date format with MMM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f422cf1-6782-43a1-8142-401fa809ca63/vs-report-designer-2005date-format-with-mmm?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: Drectly doing this did not have any effect. I deleted the field and then used the CDate function (without any format function) and specified the format as dd-MMM-yyyy it then worked.

Comment: This is also useful info. Thanks